# I'm not feeling like VS I don't feel like

Tags: expressions, present-continuous, idiomatic-language, present-simple

As far as I know, two phrases are accepted (I'm not feeling like OR I don't feel like), but I don't really sure about the point of difference, my guesses are:

> I'm not feeling like dancing...- now (not in general)
>
> I don't feel like dancing ...- in general

Question:

Are my guesses right? if they aren't, correct them please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's idiomatic and common to say:

> > I don't feel like.....

meaning, that I'm not inclined to, I'm not in the mood to.... On the other hand:

> > I'm not feeling like

may be correct but it's not often heard. Much more common are expressions such as:

> > I'm not feeling well
> >
> > I'm not feeling up to/for it

(More at: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222520/what-does-i-am-not-feeling-up-for-it-mean-when-can-you-use-this)